# How to Create Tabbed Code Blocks in Mkdocs or Sphinx?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, mkdocs

Is there a way to create tabbed code blocks like the following in Mkdocs or Sphinx?

[image]

Comment: Can't say for sure about Sphinx (did you check their plugins), but MkDocs does not offer such a feature out of the box. You would probably need some sort of JavaScript/CSS solution to manipulate how a codeblock is displayed. Although, you could check third-party-extensions for Markdown. Maybe someone has already built something.

Comment: Thanks Waylan. I'll keep looking and perhaps someone has built an extesion as you mention.

Comment: Sphinx-tabs seems your solution for Sphinx https://github.com/djungelorm/sphinx-tabs

Answer (score 2):

There is [sphinxcontrib-osexample](https://github.com/svx/sphinxcontrib-osexample), which tries to implement such a feature, but it's very rudimentary!

**Example from their documentation:**
[image: f]

Answer (score 2):

For mkdocs you have the [pymdownx.tabbed extension](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/tabbed/).

You would have to declare it in your `mkdocs.yaml` file:

```yaml
markdown_extensions:
  - pymdownx.tabbed
```

Then the syntax in your markdown file would be [taken from the documentation]:

```
=== "Tab 1"
    Markdown **content**.

    Multiple paragraphs.

=== "Tab 2"
    More Markdown **content**.

    - list item a
    - list item b
```

It is guaranteed to work well with the [material](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/getting-started/) theme (see the [page with examples](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/content-tabs/)). For other themes, you would have to try it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [markdown-fenced-code-tabs](https://github.com/yacir/markdown-fenced-code-tabs) extension. I use it with `MkDocs`.

````
## Tabs 

```curl
$ curl -O wget http://example.com/pk.zip
```

```wget
$ wget http://example.com/pk.zip
```

## Single block

```
$ ls -lisa
```
````

**Becomes**

[image]

Comment: It is possible to use "markdown-fenced-code-tabs" in a Sphinx project (using markdown content via the m2r2 extension)?

Answer (score 1):

And also https://github.com/mikecules/MarkdownBSCodeTabs for mkdocs that does the same as markdown-fenced-code-tabs

There is an issue with both of them, if you include multiples code block with the same language, they all will be displayed with the same name, but you wont be able to switch between them.

Furthermore the spark documentation (written in Jekyll) has nice code tabs.

See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is an mkdocs extension -[CodeHilite](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/code_hilite/)- which leverages another extension -[SuperFences](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/superfences/)- which works wonders for code examples in different languages / situations. This is part of the [PyMdown](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/) collection of extensions.

[image: CodeHilite example]

In addition, CodeHilite provides:

- Syntax highlighting for more than 300 languages (the one supported by [Pygments](http://pygments.org/languages/))
- Line numbering
- Line highlights
  [image: List item]